# need a workaround for the webview memory leak issue in android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I use Webview in an Activity in my app to display html.

The application does other things as well, the activity showing the html page may appear and disappear many times, depending on what the user does.

Unfortunately, the Webview has a memory leak, causing the activity that contained it to stay in memory. If this activity will show many times, the application will eventually run out of memory.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5067
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9375

The Suggested workaround was to pass to the webview the application context instead of the activity context, but this doesn't work for all webviews.

Is there anything else I can do? can I "reuse" one instance of the webview activity over and over somehow? hiding it when I'm done (instead of finishing it) and showing it when I need (instead of creating it).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but you could try:

Create a class MyActivity that extends Activity, make all your activities in your project extend MyActivity. Create a WebView inside your MyActivity and make the children use the parents webview...

Comment: are you talking about a static webview or not?

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry I was wrong, this way you will each time create a new WebView... Well I don't know if you could use a WebView initiated by ActivityA in ActivityB or not...

Comment: I believe the best I can do is shrink the leaked activity so the leak will be something I could live with.

Comment: Have you tried using a webview created in Activity A in Activity B?